# How do I connect my mongoDB schema/models?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm new and trying to set up my noSQL DB model and am struggling. The intention is that "venues" can create events (tied to the venue), and "artists" can match-to and subsequently plan events. If you're an artist, you could also look at your dashboard and see the events you've played, so I need to connect Artists to Venues/events but don't know how.

Below is my Venue model. It works fine in my app, but where do I add Artists in?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VenueSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    location: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Venue', VenueSchema);
```

Below is my Artist model. I haven't tested this one but I think it will work okay.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const artistSchema = newSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Artist must have a name']
    },
    genre: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Contact email required']
    },
})
```

Other than Artist and Venue, I'd like "events" to contain attributes "time" and "date". However, I have no idea where to fit events into the model.. How do I connect "events" between the two models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design it like this

`Venue` schema (Same as yours): Where all the venues can be maintained independently of events and artists.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VenueSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  price: Number,
  description: String,
  location: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Venue', VenueSchema);
```

`Artist` schema (same as yours): Where all the artists can be maintained independently of events and venues.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const artistSchema = newSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Artist must have a name']
  },
  genre: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Contact email required']
  },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Artist', artistSchema);
```

`Events` schema: This is where artists and venue come together. Since there will be continuous operations on events (like updating progress) it can be done independently of artists and venues.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
  venue_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Venue',
    index: true
  },
  artist_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Artist',
    index: true
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,  // Captures both date and time
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

Comment: Ahh, and then the events schema ties it all together. I like that idea. Thanks for the feedback!!!